# Why does host and nslookup think IP address is a hostname?

Tags: dns, xargs, arguments

Why does this command fail (this is a simplified version of the actual command)?

```
/tmp $ echo 74.6.231.20 | xargs -n1 -I {} echo "$(host -d {})"
Trying "74.6.231.20.<REDACTED>.<REDACTED>.com"
Trying "74.6.231.20"
Host 74.6.231.20 not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Received 95 bytes from 10.163.24.1#53 in 1 ms
```

The *host* command is treating 74.6.231.20 as a hostname instead of an IP address which is why it's failing (ie there is no 74.6.231.20 hostname/FQDN).

Directly specifying the IP address works:

```
/tmp $ echo 216.58.195.78 |  xargs -n1 -I {} echo "$(host -d 216.58.195.78)"
Trying "78.195.58.216.in-addr.arpa"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 21425
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;78.195.58.216.in-addr.arpa.    IN  PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
78.195.58.216.in-addr.arpa. 85730 IN    PTR sfo07s16-in-f78.1e100.net.
78.195.58.216.in-addr.arpa. 85730 IN    PTR sfo07s16-in-f14.1e100.net.

Received 113 bytes from 10.163.24.1#53 in 2 ms
```

Eliminating the *echo* command also works:

```
/tmp echo 74.6.231.20 | xargs -n1 -I {} sh -c  "(host {})"
20.231.6.74.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer media-router-fp73.prod.media.vip.ne1.yahoo.com.
```

The problem seems to be the combination of xargs with echo and how xargs is doing the {} string replacement.

p.s. I'm aware there's work-arounds, I'm mainly interested in finding the interaction that's broken that prevents this command from running successfully. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not in front of a Linux box right now, but I think you need to escape the command or `bash` is processing it before xargs gets it. So you want to try single quotes at the end: `xargs ... echo '$(stuff {})'` - this _might_ be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your shell performs variables and command substitution on command-line arguments before passing them to commands as arguments, so the `$(host -d {})` happens before the `xargs`. The second `echo` command actually outputs this:

```
Trying "{}.<REDACTED>.<REDACTED>.com"
Trying "{}"
Host {} not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Received 95 bytes from 10.163.24.1#53 in 1 ms
```

Then `xargs` replaces `{}` in the output with the IP address, making it look like the `host` command malfunctioned. You can see it for yourself by using `set -x` before running the pipeline:

```
( set -x; echo 74.6.231.20 | xargs -n1 -I {} echo "$(host -d {})" )

+ echo 74.6.231.20
++ host -d '{}'
+ xargs -n1 -I '{}' echo 'Trying "{}.<REDACTED>.<REDACTED>.com"
Trying "{}"
Host {} not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Received 95 bytes from 10.163.24.1#53 in 1 ms'
Trying "74.6.231.20.<REDACTED>.<REDACTED>.com"
Trying "74.6.231.20"
Host 74.6.231.20 not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Received 95 bytes from 10.163.24.1#53 in 1 ms
```

In this specific example, if all you wanted to do was to show the output of `host`, it's not necessary to capture it and then explicitly `echo` it. It's sufficient to just do this:

```
echo 74.6.231.20 | xargs -n1 host -d
```

EDIT:

Here's an example of how to pass the `xargs` input to more than one command. This works because `bash` will assign any arguments after the `-c` command as positional parameters, starting with `$0`.

```
echo 74.6.231.20 | xargs -n1 -I '{}' /bin/bash -c 'echo "$0"; host -d "$0"' '{}'
```

Comment: Holy mackerel. I would have never figured this out.Thanks so much for the clear answer and a way to troubleshoot this. I've been using bash for decades and wasn't aware of when variables are substituted.

BTW: The reason for the second echo was I wanted to print the IP address and the host command output on a single line:

/tmp $ echo 74.6.231.20 | xargs -n1 -I {} echo "{} $(host -d {})"

Comment: I've updated my answer with one example of how you could do this.